# Passing a closure to a generic function

Tags: rust

I have a function that takes a const generic value and a closure.

```rust
pub fn parse<const N: usize, F>(consumer: F) 
    where F: Fn(usize)
{
    consumer(N * 2);
}
```

The function compiles fine. But I get a compile error when I try to call it.

```rust
parse::<10>(|n| {
    println!("Closure called with: {}", n);
});
```

The error is:

```
this function takes 2 generic arguments but 1 generic argument was supplied
```

I used a type placeholder and it actually worked.

```rust
parse::<10, _>(|n| {
    println!("Closure called with: {}", n);
});
```

Is there no other elegant way of doing this? If the const generics wasn't there then Rust will have no problem inferring the closure type.

Comment: AFAIK, no unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a so-called "impl trait in argument positon" instead of a generic type parameter:

```rust
pub fn parse<const N: usize>(consumer: impl Fn(usize))
{
    consumer(N * 2);
}
```

This is very similar to your original code, except that the type of `consumer` must always be implicit and cannot be explicitly specified with type parameters.

Comment: This works. AFAIK impl in argument is just a syntactic sugar for generics. I wonder why the generic version (that I posted) doesn't work. May be someday it will work.

Comment: Note that this only works since [Rust 1.63.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/08/11/Rust-1.63.0.html#turbofish-for-generics-in-functions-with-impl-trait).

Comment: @RajV The Rust reference specifically [says this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html#anonymous-type-parameters): "_That is, `impl Trait` in argument position is syntactic sugar for a generic type parameter like `<T: Trait>`, **except that the type is anonymous and doesn't appear in the GenericParams list.**_"

Comment: @RajV In other words, _if_ you have a generic parameter list, you _must_ specify all generic type parameters (though they may be wildcards like `_`), but that doesn't apply to impl traits in argument positions. Conversely, impl traits in argument positions _cannot_ be specified in a generic parameter list.